# Extending RocketChip register

Tags: riscv

Is it possible to extend the register set available in RocketChip? If so, how do I go about it?
I am trying to add a new instruction that will be able to move data from the existing RISCV registers to an extended set of registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible?  Rocket-chip and the corresponding RISC-V toolchain is free and open-source, so yes, you can certainly modify it to your heart's content (and there's certainly nothing technical that would prevent you from doing so either).

However, this would be a huge project that touches a lot of stuff, so you'll have to attack each part in pieces. Regarding the ISA, you'd have to start with:

1) learning how to add instructions to "gas", the GNU assembler.

This will be even harder than normal, because you're attempting to add an entire new set of registers (rather than extending the existing integer set or floating point set).  I'd probably start by looking at how vector registers have been handled as a start.

2) Once you can generate assembly code that does what you want, you'll need to modify the spike ISA simulator to execute and test your programs.  That's pretty simple - but you'll have to stare at the code base for a while, and learn how to add new instructions to it (see riscv.org talks on how to add custom instructions and accelerators to spike).

3) Once you can generate code and test it on an ISA simulator, then you can move forward with hacking Rocket-chip itself.  The rocket core is a relatively straight forward 5-stage, in-order pipeline, so you're left to your own creativity on how to add a new register set to it.  Look at the floating point unit code and the floating point register file for inspiration.

But I'm a gcc guy, maybe your adventure would be easier to do in llvm?

Comment: Hello Chris, Thank you for the answer. I am fairly new to using the rocket core. Another doubt, how is adding a new set of registers different from existing the existing integer set as you mentioned.